# Bootstrap Navbar Displays Incorrect in Nav Component Vue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have an issue with my Bootstrap navbar displaying within my Vue component. It currently displays as a stacked greyed out button. Almost like it thinks it is on a small device.

[image: Navbar Currently]

The full code for the navbar can be found [here](https://github.com/Callum9362/investment-site/blob/main/src/components/Nav.vue) . I am not sure what I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

In **bootstrap 4.5**, the `navbar-toggler button` is different as yours. Then, to change icon colors (to see it) of the button depending on the navbar style, add `navbar-light` if your navbar is clear, or `navbar-dark` if it is sombre.

Comment: Your answer was correct. I was looking at the documentation for version 3.3 not 4.5. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```